# ¿Como disminuyo el alpha SOLO del componente padre del layout.xml?

Tags: android, xml

Buenas, tengo algo como lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El View que contiene los EditText es un CardView, al cual intento bajarle la opacidad sin que afecte a los demas elementos, pero solo veo la propiedad alpha y esta afecta todos los componentes internos del Viewas así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Hay alguna forma de bajar la opacidad sin disminuir la de los componentes hijos?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar un Framelayout, luego dentro un imageview que sería el background y tu login form.

Al imageview le pones transparencia y así no afecta a tu login form :)

Algo así :

```
<FrameLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/background" 
        android:alpha="0.3" />
    <LinearLayout>
        <Button />
        <Button />
    </LinearLayout>     
</FrameLayout>
```